# Submit form for ajaxForm with using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am injecting JS from an iOS app to a web app. I control code for both. I am trying to write javascript that takes input from a barcode scanner and then puts it in a web form and then submits the form. I use the [jQuery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin to make all the forms ajax. I use ajaxForm.

I want to make the code as generic as possible in case I change the front-end code down the road (For example removing ajaxForm). My goal is to simply have a set of ids and when it matches an id to changes the value of the input and then submits the form. This form could be ajax or a regular form; but the iOS app should NOT know the implementation details. Is there a way to do this in vanilla js?

```
var scan_ids = ['item','search'];

for(var k=0;k<scan_ids.length;k++)
{
    var scan_id = scan_ids[k];

    if (document.getElementById(scan_id))
    {
        document.getElementById(scan_id).value = "[SCAN]";

        if (scan_id == "item")
        {
             /*I don't want to do this as I am bound to ajaxSubmit; 
I would rather trigger a form submit and have it use ajaxForm
 that is bound to it. If I do .submit() it ignores the ajaxForm */

            $('#add_item_form').ajaxSubmit({target: "#register_container", beforeSubmit: salesBeforeSubmit, success:itemScannedSuccess});


        $('#add_item_form').submit(); //(WORKS and submits via ajax)
        document.getElementById('add_item_form').submit(); //(SUBMITS; DOES NOT AJAX)
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking whether you can submit a form in vanilla JS without using a library/framework?

Comment: Correct. But I am trying to do it without even knowing the form or use jQuery. Just an id (if possible). See the last do lines in if (scan_id == 'item')

Comment: Apologies, I didn't understand before. Okay, so you want to submit a form in plain JS, but via AJAX?

Comment: I want it i work exactly like  `$('#add_item_form').submit();` in jQuery the form is actually using ajaxForm but I didn't need to know that for it to work. is there a way in vanilla js to work JUST like that?

Comment: Can I ask why you'd like to use vanilla JS to do this? You will essentially be re-writing a module that already works.

Comment: I guess your right. I will stick with the simple jQuery solution.

Answer (score 9):

In order to submit a form using vanilla/plain JS, simply call the `submit` method on the form:

```
document.getElementById('formId').submit();
```

However, it sound like you want to make an AJAX request. These are different from standard HTTP requests. They are called [XMLHttp Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

When you submit a form using a plain HTTP request (what happens when you use `form.submit()`), the browser populates the POST/GET variables that get sent to the server by using the information inside the `<form>` that is being sent.

When sending an XMLHttp Request, that work is not done for you. You must do it yourself.

As far as I can tell, this is the bulk of what [jQuery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is doing. It is collecting the information in your form, populating an XMLHttp Request, and then submitting the form to the server using so-called AJAX technology.

You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26556347/726766) answer useful; someone has written a plain Javascript method for submitting a form via AJAX. Here is the method from that answer:

```
/**
 * Takes a form node and sends it over AJAX.
 * @param {HTMLFormElement} form - Form node to send
 * @param {function} callback - Function to handle onload. 
 *                              this variable will be bound correctly.
 */

function ajaxPost (form, callback) {
    var url = form.action,
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //This is a bit tricky, [].fn.call(form.elements, ...) allows us to call .fn
    //on the form's elements, even though it's not an array. Effectively
    //Filtering all of the fields on the form
    var params = [].filter.call(form.elements, function(el) {
        //Allow only elements that don't have the 'checked' property
        //Or those who have it, and it's checked for them.
        return typeof(el.checked) === 'undefined' || el.checked;
        //Practically, filter out checkboxes/radios which aren't checekd.
    })
    .filter(function(el) { return !!el.name; }) //Nameless elements die.
    .filter(function(el) { return !el.disabled; }) //Disabled elements die.
    .map(function(el) {
        //Map each field into a name=value string, make sure to properly escape!
        return encodeURIComponent(el.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(el.value);
    }).join('&'); //Then join all the strings by &

    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-form-urlencoded");

    //.bind ensures that this inside of the function is the XHR object.
    xhr.onload = callback.bind(xhr); 

    //All preperations are clear, send the request!
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

It's probably worth noting that the original poster of this code is using methods that won't work on some older browsers. Notably browsers that do not support the [ECMAScript 5](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) implementation.

My advice would be to stick to using the plugin you already have. I can't see a reason to re-invent the wheel. Rest assured that your jQuery library is using vanilla Javascript under the hood.

Comment: I tested this in Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit) and for input fields el.checked equals false. So I included this `|| el.type !== 'checkbox' || el.type !== 'radio'` to that line. I didn't want to edit this post without making this comment first. Would you say that with this, checking for `typeof(el.checked) === 'undefined'` is necessary?

Comment: Appears those `.filter(function(el) {...})` methods need closing parentheses. Lines 21,22. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @danfo well spotted. Thanks

Comment: `!el.disabled` in the filter.